How to processing points' attributes(like uv coordinates or normals) in CGAL library?
As known, the cgal library only process the 3d model without points' attributes. But, I have specific models with those attributes(like uv coordinates or normals or colors). I want to find a effective way to process my models and update those points' attributes automatically.If cgal can not do this, are there some other librarys can achieve this purpose?

The class CGAL::Point_set_3 offers storage for points with properties. What algorithms do you have in mind to operate on points with properties?

The 3D boolean operation for meshes

By the way, I found the way :  auto uv_map = point_set.add_property_map<UV>("uv", UV(0, 0)).first;     auto normal_map = point_set.add_property_map<Vector>("normal", CGAL::NULL_VECTOR).first;  to add points' attributes. But, the map attributes can not update after processing.
